# How can i read the output from an executed shell command?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've read numerous questions about this subject, and even 2 which have accepted answers, which then have in the comment the same issue as i'm experiencing.

So what I want to do is catch the output of this command (which works in the command line)

```
 sudo /usr/bin/atq
```

in my Python program.

This is my code (which is an accepted answer in another question)

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

output = Popen(['sudo /usr/bin/atq', ''], stdout=PIPE)
print output.stdout.read()
```

and this is the result:

```
  File "try2.py", line 3, in <module>
    output = Popen(['sudo /usr/bin/atq', ''], stdout=PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1259, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Why oh why is this the result (in Python 2.7, on a debian Raspbarry Wheezy install)?

Comment: Try `subprocess.check_output()`.

Comment: Whow, what a quick answer.... and it works! Can you post it as an answer...

Answer (score 6):

I believe all you need to do is change,

```
output = Popen(['sudo /usr/bin/atq'], stdout=PIPE)
```

to

```
output = Popen(['sudo', '/usr/bin/atq'], stdout=PIPE)
```

I get the same error when I include multiple arguments as a single string in the `args` list.

Answer (score 3):

The arguments to `Popen` need to be a list, you could use `shlex` to handle this automatically for you

```
import shlex
args = shlex.split('sudo /usr/bin/atq')
print args
```

produces

```
['sudo', '/usr/bin/atq']
```

which you can then pass to `Popen`. Then you'll need to `communicate` with the process you've created.
Have a go with [`.communicate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) (note arguments to `Popen` here are a list!) ie

```
prc = Popen(['sudo', '/usr/bin/atq'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
output, stderr = prc.communicate()
print output
```

`Popen` returns the `subprocess` handle, which you need to `communicate` with to get the output. Note - adding `stderr=PIPE` will give you access to `STDERR` as well as `STDOUT`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`subprocess.check_output()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output):

```
subprocess.check_output(['sudo', '/usr/bin/atq'])
```

example:

```
In [11]: print subprocess.check_output(["ps"])
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 4547 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
 4599 pts/0    00:00:00 python
 4607 pts/0    00:00:00 python
 4697 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
```

**help()**:

```
In [12]: subprocess.check_output?
Type:       function
String Form:<function check_output at 0xa0e9a74>
File:       /usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py
Definition: subprocess.check_output(*popenargs, **kwargs)
Docstring:
Run command with arguments and return its output as a byte string.

If the exit code was non-zero it raises a CalledProcessError.  The
CalledProcessError object will have the return code in the returncode
attribute and output in the output attribute.

The arguments are the same as for the Popen constructor.
```